# BroadcastGradientArgs no documentation provided

Tags: tensorflow

I am creating my custom ops. While inspecting the ops in back prop, I am coming across `BroadcastGradientArgs`.

Does anyone has any idea what does this do?

Answer (score 1):

it is an internal op that returns the axis of reduction given two tensor shapes. Notice that the return values of this is always used for reduce_sum. ops that support broadcasting (an op involving a tensor of lesser rank or shape) needed to have a reduction function so that the resulting gradient has the same original size. It has the effect of summing individual gradients into one value.